# Strange Python ctypes behavior. Always loads the m (math) library

Tags: python, ctypes

Can someone explain to me why the following Python code works?

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

boblib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("bob_is_your_uncle"))
boblib.cos.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]
boblib.cos.restype = ctypes.c_double
print(boblib.cos(0)) # This prints out "1.0"
```

I am 1000% sure that there is no "bob_is_your_uncle" library on my filesystem. Yet, it seems like ctypes loads the `m` library. Why is this happening?

Also, if I do this: `print(boblib)`, I get this:

`<CDLL 'None', handle 7f6a80f6d170 at 0x7f6a7f34d0b8>`

What does `CDLL 'None'` mean?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Doing a `--version` on both my Python interpreters I get:
`Python 3.6.5rc1` and `Python 2.7.14+`. The above code gives the same result on both versions. My OS is Debian (Testing repo).

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: Python 3.6.5rc1 and Python 2.7.14+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not loading the math library. It appears to be loading the Python executable itself, which has `cos` linked in.

There is indeed no library named `bob_is_your_uncle`, so `find_library` returns `None`. (That's where the `None` comes from in the output you're seeing.)

On Unix, the `LoadLibrary` logic has a [specific check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#L1337) that translates a `None` name to a null pointer for the underlying `dlopen` routine. `dlopen` has [special handling](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) for a null name:

> If *filename* is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main program.

In fact, on Unix, `ctypes.pythonapi` is [created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L436) as

```
pythonapi = PyDLL(None)
```

explaining why the `None` handling is there in the first place. The CDLL object you've created is *almost* like `ctypes.pythonapi`, except that it doesn't hold the GIL for function calls or check for exceptions (because CDLL instead of PyDLL), so it's useless for interacting with the actual C Python API.